# How to remove white border when unfocusing from TreeView?

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I have just started playing around with CSS in my JavaFX project and ran into a problem I could not solve. I have a TreeView that serves as a main menu and I wanted to get rid of any focus/unfocus borders that appear. I have managed to fixe the issue with a blue border appearing when interacting with the TreeView (focusing), completely removing it, however this white border appears every time I interact with something else.

I have tried looking online for solutions to this problem, however I could not find any. I have tried altering the CSS file in different ways featured in similar focus/unfocus problems but none of them worked.

My CSS file:

```
.grid-pane {
    -fx-background-color: #181818;
}

.tree-view, .tree-cell {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

#mainMenu .tree-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0.25em 0em 0.25em 0em;
    -fx-font-size: 28px;
    -fx-background-color: #181818;
}

#mainMenu .tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow  {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
#mainMenu .tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

#mainMenu .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

[When focused (desired outcome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BEzr.png)

[When unfocused (white border)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXJCL.png)

Sorry for the bad English, as it is not my native language.
Thank you for your support!

Comment: Do you want to remove the white border which comes top of the page? As Only difference am seeing between two?

Comment: Did you try `tree.setFocusTraversable(false);`?

Comment: `tree.setFocusTraversable(false);` made it so the white border always appears. @M.S.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer just now actually. I added `-fx-background-insets: 1;` to tree-view css only and it no longer appears. Thank you to everyone who tried to help so far!

```
.tree-view {
    -fx-background-insets: 1;
}
```